# how to make these functions generic, in F#?

Tags: struct, f#

I have these two functions:

```
// load from cache
let private loadFromCacheAsync filespec =
    async {
        let! bytes = File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filespec) |> Async.AwaitTask
        let result = 
            use pBytes = fixed bytes
            let sourceSpan = Span<byte>(NativePtr.toVoidPtr pBytes, bytes.Length) 
            MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ShortTradeData>(sourceSpan).ToArray()
        return (result |> Array.map (fun x -> x.ToTradeData())) 
    }    

// save to cache
let private saveToCacheAsync filespec (data: TradeData array) =
    Directory.CreateDirectory cacheFolder |> ignore
    let sizeStruct = sizeof<ShortTradeData>
    let smallData = data |> Array.map ShortTradeData.FromTradeData
    use ptr = fixed smallData
    let nativeSpan = Span<byte>(NativePtr.toVoidPtr ptr, data.Length * sizeStruct).ToArray()
    File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filespec, nativeSpan) |> Async.AwaitTask
```

and I'm trying to make them generic:

```
// load from cache
let private loadFromCacheAsync<'a> filespec =
    async {
        let! bytes = File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filespec) |> Async.AwaitTask
        let result = 
            use pBytes = fixed bytes
            let sourceSpan = Span<byte>(NativePtr.toVoidPtr pBytes, bytes.Length) 
            MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, 'a>(sourceSpan).ToArray()
        return result
    }    

// save to cache
let private saveToCacheAsync<'a> filespec (data: 'a array) =
    Directory.CreateDirectory cacheFolder |> ignore
    let sizeStruct = sizeof<'a>
    use ptr = fixed data
    let nativeSpan = Span<byte>(NativePtr.toVoidPtr ptr, data.Length * sizeStruct).ToArray()
    File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filespec, nativeSpan) |> Async.AwaitTask
```

the first one fails to compile with:

"No overloads known for method Cast"

and the second one fails to compile with:

"A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when 'a: unmanaged'

so I can make the second one compile by changing the function:

> ```
> let private saveToCacheAsync<'a when 'a: unmanaged> filespec (data: 'a array) =
> ```

but I assumed that "when 'a: struct" would make more sense. Upon reading the doc, it looks like unmanaged works for structs with primitive (unmanaged) types... still don't know why struct doesn't work.

But for the first function, I don't have any idea what should be done to fix it.

The full error message is:

```
  DataCache.fs(28, 17): [FS0041] No overloads match for method 'Cast'.
Known type of argument: Span<byte>
Available overloads:
 - MemoryMarshal.Cast<'TFrom,'TTo when 'TFrom: (new: unit -> 'TFrom) and 'TFrom: struct and 'TFrom :> ValueType and 'TTo: (new: unit -> 'TTo) and 'TTo: struct and 'TTo :> ValueType>(span: ReadOnlySpan<'TFrom>) : ReadOnlySpan<'TTo>
 - MemoryMarshal.Cast<'TFrom,'TTo when 'TFrom: (new: unit -> 'TFrom) and 'TFrom: struct and 'TFrom :> ValueType and 'TTo: (new: unit -> 'TTo) and 'TTo: struct and 'TTo :> ValueType>(span: Span<'TFrom>) : Span<'TTo>
```

and if I look at the types it takes:

- 'TTo when 'TFrom: (new: unit -> 'TFrom)
- 'TFrom: struct
- 'TFrom :> ValueType
- 'TTo: (new: unit -> 'TTo)
- 'TTo: struct
- 'TTo :> ValueType

we care about TTo here:

- 'TTo when 'TFrom: (new: unit -> 'TFrom)
- 'TTo: (new: unit -> 'TTo)
- 'TTo: struct
- 'TTo :> ValueType

I still don't get it: it looks like it needs to be a struct, and can be cast as a value type (struct then?) and have an empty constructor? I don't understand the first line.

Comment: `unmanaged` constraint is more restrictive than `struct`. It implies struct that doesn't have references in it. This is important because serializing references is dangerous as they have different size on x86 and x64; reference is pointer to memory, which shouldn't be deserialized, because application may (and will) run in different address space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `loadFromCacheAsync`'s "from" type parameter is always `byte`, you only need three constraints on its "to" parameter, which you've called `'a`:

- `'a: (new: unit -> 'a)`
- `'a: struct`
- `'a :> System.ValueType`

The last two do seem redundant, but I assume this is just an artifact of .NET's underlying requirements.

The resulting signature for `loadFromCacheAsync` is:

```ml
let private loadFromCacheAsync<'a when 'a: (new: unit -> 'a) and 'a: struct and 'a :> ValueType> filespec =
```